# React file upload not set to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, file-upload

I am trying to implement an file upload button, where the data is then sent to an API.
As the input field should not be visible and only the button should trigger the upload dialog, I have implemented it this way.

> Problem: The File is not set to state, so I can not use a POST via axios in the `onChange` function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useAxios from 'axios-hooks';

export default function BusinessCalendar(props: Props): React.ReactElement {
  const hiddenFileInput = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<any>();

  const onSubmit = (): void => {
    if (hiddenFileInput.current) {
      hiddenFileInput.current.click();
    }
  };

  const onChange = async (event: any): Promise<void> => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('File', selectedFile);

    console.log('file', selectedFile, formData); // => returns `undefined`
    
    await register({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      data: {
        body: formData.get('File'), // => UNDEFINED
      },
    });
  };

  return (
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={hiddenFileInput}
          onChange={onChange}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
        />
        <Button
          onClick={onSubmit}
          label="Add new"
          icon="icon-plus"
          type="secondary"
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React's events are [synthetic](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) and are reused after handler completes. And just as interpretator finds `await` operator the current execution frame gets terminated (handler completes) and React [clears](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html) event's object.

Consider using `event.persist()` to override that behavior.